# x64 memset core, is passed buffer address truncated?

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, assembly, gdb

**1. Problem Background**

Recently a core dump occurred on one of our on-line search server. The core happens in `memset()` due to the attempt to write to an invalid address, and hence received the SIGSEGV signal. The following information is from dmsg:

`is_searcher_ser[17405]: segfault at 000000002c32a668 rip 0000003da0a7b006 rsp 0000000053abc790 error 6`

The environment of our on-line servers goes as follows:

- OS:    RHEL 5.3
- Kernel: 2.6.18-131.el5.custom, x86_64 (64-bit)
- GCC:  4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)
- Glibc:  glibc-2.5-49.6

The following is the relevant code snippet:

```
CHashMap<…>::CHashMap(…)
{
     …
     typedef HashEntry *HashEntryPtr;              
     m_ppEntry = new HashEntryPtr[m_nHashSize];   // m_nHashSize is 389 when core
     assert(m_ppEntry != NULL);
     memset(m_ppEntry, 0x0, m_nHashSize*sizeof(HashEntryPtr)); // Core in this memset() invocation 
     …
}
```

The assembly code of the above code is:

```
…
0x000000000091fe9e <+110>:   callq  0x502638 <_Znam@plt>  // new HashEntryPtr[m_nHashSize]
0x000000000091fea3 <+115>:   mov    0xc(%rbx),%edx         // Get the value of m_nHashSize
0x000000000091fea6 <+118>:   mov    %rax,%rdi               // Put m_ppEntry pointer to %rdi for later memset invocation
0x000000000091fea9 <+121>:   mov    %rax,0x20(%rbx)        // Store the pointer to m_ppEntry member variable(%rbx holds the this pointer)
0x000000000091fead <+125>:   xor    %esi,%esi               // Generate 0
0x000000000091feaf <+127>:   shl    $0x3,%rdx               // m_nHashSize*sizeof(HashEntryPtr)
0x000000000091feb3 <+131>:   callq  0x502b38 <memset@plt> // Call the memset() function
…
```

In the core dump, the assembly of `memset@plt` is:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0x502b38
Dump of assembler code for function memset@plt:
    0x0000000000502b38 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x771b92(%rip)        # 0xc746d0 <memset@got.plt>
    0x0000000000502b3e <+6>:     pushq  $0x53
    0x0000000000502b43 <+11>:    jmpq   0x5025f8
End of assembler dump.
 (gdb) x/ag 0x0000000000502b3e+0x771b92
    0xc746d0 <memset@got.plt>:      0x3da0a7acb0 <memset>
 (gdb) disassemble 0x3da0a7acb0
 Dump of assembler code for function memset:
    0x0000003da0a7acb0 <+0>:     cmp    $0x1,%rdx
    0x0000003da0a7acb4 <+4>:     mov    %rdi,%rax
    …
```

For the above GDB analysis， we know that the address of `memset()` has been resolved in the relocation PLT table. That is to say, the first `jmpq   *0x771b92(%rip)` will directly jump to the first instruction of function `memset()`. Besides, the program had run nearly one day on-line, the relocation address of `memset()` should have been already resolved earlier.

**2. Weird phenomenon**

This core fired at the instruction `=> 0x0000003da0a7b006 <+854>:   mov    %rdx,-0x8(%rdi)` in the `memset()`. Actually this is the instruction in the `memset()` to set the `0` at the right begin position of the buffer which is the first parameter of `memset()`.

When cored , in frame 0, the value of `$rdi` is `0x2c32a670` ,and `$rax` is `0x2c32a668`. From the assembly analysis and off-line test, `$rax` should hold the source buffer of the `memset`, i.e., the first parameter of `memset()`.

So, in our example, `$rax` should be same as the address of `m_ppEntry`, the value of which is stored in the `this` object (`this` pointer is stored in `%rbx`) first before it is zeroed by `memset` later. However, the value of `m_ppEntry` is `0x2ab02c32a668`.

Then use `info files` GDB command to check, the address `0x2c32a668` is indeed invalid (not mapped), and address `0x2ab02c32a668` is a valid address.

**3. Why it is weird?**

The weird place of this core is that: If the real address of `memset` has been resolved already(very very probably), then there are only very few instructions between the operation to put the pointer value into `m_ppEntry` and the attempt to `memset` it. And actually the value of register `$rax` (holding the passed buffer address) are not changed at all during these instructions. So, how can `m_ppEntry` isn’t equal to `$rax`?

What is weird *More* is that: when core, the value of `$rax` (`0x2c32a668`) is actually the value of lower 4 bytes of `m_ppEntry` (`0x2ab02c32a668`). If there is indeed some relationship between the two values, is the `m_ppEntry` parameter passed to `memset` being truncated? However, the involved several instructions all use `%rax`, rather than `%eax`. By the way, I cannot reproduce this issue offline.

So,

1) Which address is valid? If `0x2c32a668` is valid? Is the heap corrupted just between the several instructions? And how to paraphrase that the value of `m_ppEntry` is `0x2ab02c32a668`, and why the low 4 bytes of this two value is the same?

2) If `0x2ab02c32a668` is valid, why the address is truncated when passed into the 64-bit `memset()`? Under which condition this error will occur? I cannot reproduce this offline. Is this issue an known bug? I didn't find it through Google.

3) Or, is it due to some hardware or power issue to make the 4 higher bytes of `%rdi` passed to `memset` zeroed? (I’m very very reluctant to believe this).

**At last, any comment on this core is appreciated.**

Thanks,

Gary Hu

Comment: It all looks correct at a glance, do you have any other threads running that could conceivably have changed anything? (or tried to run this function at the same time for example)

Comment: Actually it's a constructor so the 2nd part is not likely at all.

Comment: Yes, we have other theading running, but this HashMap containing m_ppEntry is not shared between threads.And the gap between the places to set the pointer to m_ppEntry and the attemp to memset the pointer only have less 20 instructions. Besides, %rdi is not changed at all when going into memset, which holding the passed buffer address.

Comment: What is the version of GCC the application is built with, and do you handle signals? There was a bug in GCC 4.3 and 4.4, that may explain the symptoms: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39118

Comment: Just for completeness, you could ditch the `memset` and simply say `m_ppEntry = new HashEntryPtr[m_nHashSize](0)` (i.e. use _initializing_ `new`).

Comment: Sorry to correct myself, `m_ppEntry = new HashEntryPtr[m_nHashSize]()` (no argument). You'd notice though as the compiler complains.

Comment: @Frank,it's a convenient way to use new. Thanks.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, our GCC version is  4.1.2. The bug you mentioned is about red zone on the stack, but this core fails at the attempt to access the memory on the *heap*.

Comment: @user1878089 "attempt to access the memory on the heap" -- no it's not. Something *truncated* your pointer while it was in register (between instructions `0x000000000091fea9` and `0x000000000091feb3`. That something probably spilled your registers to stack, then restored them. You didn't answer the question about signals; it's kind of important.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, thanks for your comments. Yes, we deal with signals. But we block them (SIGINT,SIGTERM,SIGUSR1,SIGUSR2,SIGPIPE)using pthread_sigmask(),and only use sigwait() to deal with them predictably in  the main thread. To put simply, these signals are blocked in the working threads, so it seems that this bad thread was not interrupted by signals.

Comment: user1878089, Is ECC memory installed in your server?

Comment: I would try a data breakpoint. Setup a hardware breakpoint-on-write for m_ppEntry. The "gap of less than 20 instructions" really is a gap of between 20 and infinity instructions, due to multithreading, you never know how long ANY line of code will be delayed.

Comment: As people noted, the error must be elsewhere. You should probably use `std::vector<HashEntry*>` to do the above in one line, or replace that hash container with `__gnu_cxx::hash_map`, `std::tr1::unordered_map` or google containers. The quality of the above four lines suggests that the rest of the code may be no better, so the crash is not surprising. I've seen homegrown hash maps in finance industry that worked around 10 years in production, yet it contained a bug that made it lose nodes on collisions and nobody spotted that. I just replaced the internals of that hash with a standard hash.

Comment: Re: GCC in RHEL: It is _not_ the stock version, it probably contains backported fixes for the bugs mentioned. Check the release notes to make sure (would have to check the GCC bugzilla for bug numbers there, and see what the release notes say).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming most of the time this code works fine, given your mention of one day's running.
I agree signals are worth inspecting, it does look suspiciously like pointer truncation is happening somewhere else.

Only other thing I'm thinking it could be an issue with the new. Is there any possibly that on occasion you could end up calling an overloaded new operator?
Also for completeness what is the declaration of m_ppEntry ?
I'm assuming you're using a no throw new otherwise the `assert(m_ppEntry != NULL);` would be meaningless.